# Git missing changes in random files

Tags: git, gitlab

We are working in a team where we each commit and push our changes into the master branch for a couple of months now.

In the last week we noticed some changes were missing in random files in multiple repo's. These files showed up in our local repo's as uncommitted files. Even files that nobody touched for months. Seemingly, they were put back to an old version of itself or were deleted (because they didn't exist at that point?).
We can find the commits of those changes in the global commit log of gitlab, but when we look at the history of that specific file, the commits are missing.

It has happened twice this week that someone who only changed just one file was shown a whole lot of files in their commit list because of this problem.

Nobody is performing any fancy git commands, just pulling, committing, pushing and a conflict merge now and then.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an explicit example?

Comment: Seems to me a case of someone working on an older copy of the code, and doing a forced push to master, in effect removing some of the previous commits. If done multiple times, this can easily result in some random dev seeming to miss some random commit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if it was a (forced) commit, then it should be visible in the commit log of the file. Now it seems the file has just jumped to an old version and the last commit(s) have disappeared from the file's log. Also, the file was not touched by anybody for a while now.

Comment: There is a difference between a forced push and a forced commit...

Comment: We use TortoiseGit on Windows. I don't think it's even possible to do a forced commit/push with this.

Comment: Hmm, that was one sceneraio. Anyway, I think this is too broad as it stands, you will need to add history on the different machine using `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

Comment: What does it mean that you see the commits in history for the repo but not the file?  Does specifying `--full-history` to `git-log` change that?

Comment: With `git log --full-history [filename]` the missing commit actually shows up! How is it that this commit 'magically' disappeared as nobody touched this file for a while? Can I check what happened to it?